# Getting an ID from a one-to-many field

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to get a ID for a related Model.  I have tried several things but can not figure it out.  below is the code I am using.

```
def assign_load(request):
form = DispatchForm(request.POST or None)
loads = Load.objects.all().filter(active=True, dispatched=False, picked_up=False, delivered=False,
                                  billed=False, paid=False)
context_dict = {'dispatch' : form, 'load' : loads}
if form.is_valid():
    save_it = form.save()
    save_it.save()
    new_dispatch = Dispatch.objects.all().filter(id=save_it.id)
    print(new_dispatch.model.load_number.pk)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/dispatch/dispatch/')

return render(request, 'dispatch/dispatch_form.html', context_dict)
```

new_dispatch is the newly created record that has a one-to-many releation with a model called Loads. I need to get the load_number PK when I try to print just the new_dispatch.model.load_number I get back the following.

```
<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ForwardManyToOneDescriptor object at 0x0000029016E34710>
```

but what I need is the ID for that record so that I can updated some fields.

Thank you very much for your help, I am new to the Django world and trying to figure this stuff out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `Dispatch.objects.get(id=save_it.id)` instead of `Dispatch.objects.all().filter(id=save_it.id)`

Comment: That did the trick, thank you very much.  I guess I need to read some more on the get I would have thought what I was do would be the same thing but now I know better....thank you once again.

Comment: yes `.get()` gives you a single object (provided it exists) when `.filter()` gives you a Queryset